# Skipping header while reading CSV file

Tags: python

I am working on a project to read in colon delimited files, merge into one file remove all records that have a field that match certain criteria. The input files have 4 lines on top of each file that I need to discard. Output the final file as a colon delimited file without the unwanted records.

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import glob
import os
import sys
import datetime
import itertools
from itertools import islice


input_path = "c:\\data\\customer files\\project roo\\printer accounting\\data files\\"
output_path = "c:\\data\\customer files\\project roo\\printer accounting\\data files\\output\\"


input_files = os.path.join(input_path, '*.dat')
output_file = os.path.join(output_path,'{:%Y%m%d}-    summary.csv'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))

filewriter = csv.writer(open (output_file, 'w', newline= ''), delimiter= ':')

look_for = set(['Document Name = Microsoft Word - T.DOC'])

for input_file in glob.glob(input_files):
    with open(input_file) as csvfile:
        filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ':')
        for line in itertools.islice(csvfile,4,None):

            for row in filereader:
                #if row[3] in look_for:
                    #filewriter.writerow(none)
                #else:
                    #filewriter.writerow(row)
                print(row[0])
```

The Input file

```
Ignore 1
Ignore 2
Ignore 3
Ignore 4
Document Id= 123456 :Container ID=123123 :record status = complete : Document Name = T.DOC : Sender name = george:
Document Id= 789101 :Container ID=123123 :record status = complete : Document Name = form25 : Sender name = george:
Document Id= 121314 :Container ID=123123 :record status = complete : Document Name = ian.doc : Sender name = george:
```

Output file should be

```
 Document ID= 121314 : Container ID=123123: record status = complete : Document Name= ian.doc : Sender Name = george
```

I have put the print command just to see if I can even print the fields in the input file but I get an index out of range error.   This suggests to me that the input file columns has not been indexed   I know there are many questions on this topic but I couldn't seem to identify a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the purpose of that loop: `for line in itertools.islice(csvfile,4,None):` ? It seems to me that looping through `filereader` should be sufficient... Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Hi Sylvain  _ The input files have 4 lines on top of each file that I need to discard.  Thats why I  used the  itertools.islice

Answer (score 0):

Your `for row in filereader` loop takes `filereader` but It's inside the `for line in itertools.islice(csvfile,4,None):`which you aren't actually using for anything.

Thats why it prints the same data from filereader.

```
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ':')
    for line in itertools.islice(csvfile,4,None):

        for row in filereader:
            #if row[3] in look_for:
                #filewriter.writerow(none)
            #else:
                #filewriter.writerow(row)
            print(row[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Motheus - I forgot to mention that the input files have 4 lines on top of each file that I need to discard.    That is the reason for the itertools.islice loop.  what I cannot quite understand is why the index doesn't work

Comment: Motheus - I commented the line in question    " for line in itertool.islice(csvfiile,4,None):"     I still seem to have an index out of range error.  I am wondering if there is something unusual about the data that prevents it from creating the index?

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on a project to read in colon delimited files
>
> [...] the input files have 4 lines on top of each file that I need to discard.

In your sample code, you took the problem the wrong way. You should *chain* your iterators:

```
import csv
import itertools

input_file = "test.txt"

with open(input_file) as csvfile:
    src = itertools.islice(csvfile, 4, None)
    for row in csv.reader(src, delimiter= ':'):
        print(row[0])
```

- First, open the file. This returns a "line iterator"
- Then, use `itertools.islice` to discard whatever you need from that iterator. This will return *an other iterator* containing only the lines you want to keep.
- Finally, use that later iterator as source of data for the CSV parser (returning a third iterator on "parsed CSV rows").

---

Given that input file:

```
Ignore 1
Ignore 2
Ignore 3
Ignore 4
Document Id= 123456 :Container ID=123123 :record status = complete : Document Name = T.DOC : Sender name = george:
Document Id= 789101 :Container ID=123123 :record status = complete : Document Name = form25 : Sender name = george:
Document Id= 121314 :Container ID=123123 :record status = complete : Document Name = ian.doc : Sender name = george:
```

The above program will produce:

```
sh$ python r.py
Document Id= 123456 
Document Id= 789101 
Document Id= 121314
```

Comment: Thank you Sylvain, your explanation  was very helpful.

Comment: Sylvain  - Is there any reason why this wouldn't work if there are multiple input files ?    I still get an index error after modifying the code to match what you had shown.   If I write the file out it is fine,  but for some reason I am unable to use an index such as print(row[0])